# Is it possible to store data in multi-GPUs and calculate the average still on GPU with Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu

I'm learning pytorch recently, and this question comes up to me.

When referring to multi-GPUs, I can see many tutorials about 'DataParallel'. It splits the calculation for different GPUs, then merge the results.

How about this question? I want data stored in different GPUs, then calculate their average still on GPU. For example, if I have 4 tensors with the same shape:

```py
tensor_gpu1=tensor_c1.to(device1)
tensor_gpu2=tensor_c2.to(device2)
tensor_gpu3=tensor_c3.to(device3)
tensor_gpu4=tensor_c4.to(device4)
##then I want the average still calculated on GPU (which means no communication with CPU)
##Will it work if I just sum up and divide?
result=(tensor_gpu1+tensor_gpu2+tensor_gpu3+tensor_gpu4)/4 ##Try to add tensors on different GPU.
```

After reading some more turorials, now I'm wondering whether this will work. It's said that trying to add a CPU tensor and a GPU tensor will raise up an error. How about tensors on different GPU? It will be a few days before I can get access to an available GPU, so I can't try it out now.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I found this which seems helpful. https://blog.paperspace.com/pytorch-memory-multi-gpu-debugging/

Comment: @Reactgular That site indeed enlightens me, especially the graph of how data parallel works.

Comment: You might also want to check "torch.distributed.reduce" at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html. If you have Nvidia NCCL installed, this reduce should be able to use NVIDIA's optimized NCCL-reduce to perform the sum across distributed tensors. A quick Google also turned up https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/test/test_c10d.py. Search for "    def test_queue_reduction(self):"